# SignalR sql dependency issue

Tags: c#, signalr, sqldependency

I am using SignalR in my application, have used one hub inside which I have:

```
public class MessagesHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("getNotifications")]
    public static void GetNotifications()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateNotifications();
    }

   [HubMethodName("getChatMessages")]
    public static void GetChatMessages()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateChatMessages();
    }
}
```

My signalR connection start

```
$(function () {
    var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;

    notifications.client.updateNotifications = function () {
        getNotifications();
    };

    notifications.client.updateChatMessages = function () {
        getChatMessages();
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getNotifications();
        getChatMessages();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

And getNotifications() and getChatMessages() have ajax calls-->Controller-->MessageRepository which has GetNotifications and GetMessages functions as below:

```
 public NotificationsEntity GetNotifications(UserInfo user)
 {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
       connection.Open();
       using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"//sql query here", connection))
                {
                 command.Notification = null;
                 var notificationDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    notificationDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChangeNotifications);

                 if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ////reads the data
                    }
               }
       }
  }
  public NotificationsEntity GetMessages(ChatMessages msgs)
  {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
       connection.Open();
       using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"//sql query here", connection))
                {
                 command.Notification = null;
                 var notificationDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    notificationDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChangeNotifications);

                 if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ////reads the data
                    }
               }
          }
       }
 private void dependency_OnChangeNotifications(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs notification)
    {
        if (notification.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MessagesHub.GetNotifications();
        }
    }

    private void dependency_OnChangeChatMessages(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs notification)
    {
        if (notification.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MessagesHub.GetChatMessages();
        }
    }
```

If two persons log in, two sql dependencies are created. And if any change occurs in Db, event gets triggered in multiples of 2, first time 4 next 8 next 16 next 32 and so on. I want to limit the number of sql dependcies, for I am assuming the issue is because of that.

Msdn says :

```
SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);  
// Maintain the refence in a class member.
```

How am I going to maintain the reference so that next time it does not create new dependency but use the existing one.
Or if my asuumption is wrong and multiple triggers are for some other reason, do let me know. Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't have that code inside your hub. You should have it running [in the background](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). Probably best would be to have a separate service application always running that  sits alongside your website. When it detects a chance, it can then call the hub to notify others of the update. Don't try to do too much directly in the hub.

Comment: They are separate, my hub contains two call methods: one for notification and one for chats, the actual methods containing sql dependency exist separately in another class.

Comment: The point is that the hub *shouldn't* be calling those methods. Think about it, the hub gets instantiated everytime someone connects to it. So having some code live there responsible for listening to database changes is *not correct*. That needs to live somewhere else where you only create one instance of it. And that method should then call into your hub to announce updates.

Comment: Got your point the hubs aren't calling those methods, the hubs are calling signalr jquery functions which in turn have function call with ajax calls to call controller function. I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Isn't it because you subscribe to sql notifications each time you call GetMessages/GetNotifications and therefore you receive multiple notifications because you have multiple subscriptions? You should subscribe once when the server starts. As a side not - in your hub why do you have static hub methods and use GlobalHost to get the context? Make the methods non-static and you will be able to access Clients without any additional code.

Comment: @Pawel- I did that, called subscription only once, and event got triggered only once, next time any change in db no event triggered.

Comment: @MichaelPhilips did you eventually solved this issue?

Comment: @MichaelPhilips did you get any solution ?